# Customizing SenTest/OCUnit

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, ocunit, sentestingkit

From time to time, I have the impulse to modify some aspects of the Mac/iOS unit testing framework.  I wouldn't want to sacrifice its nice integration with XCode, but at times I find myself hankering to change some details:

- Send messages to a monitor object instead of logging them to the console
- Only log failures
- Modify the sequence of tests

Simple things like that.  Is there a reasonable way to do this, perhaps through a developer variant of the SenTest framework?

Comment: The documentation for the testing toolchains is SO sparse... it seems like Apple does't want people mucking about with it.  Checkout kiwi on github, I'd say.